# Cannot resolve symbol in CellTemplate binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a ListView control ItemsSource bound to `Producers` property and it works well. But when I try to add some DataTriggers I am getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'Up'` VS warning.
Code works but I want to get rid of warning by explicitly specifying binding source.

I tried to use RelativeSource but found that CellTemplate can not use relative source as it is not part of VisualTree.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Producers, ElementName=This}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Up">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Up}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Up}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Up}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

`This` element is defined as:

```
<Window x:Class="Helper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Helper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="900.731" Width="889.344"
        x:Name="This">
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `DataContext` in design mode. Like, `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:ViewModel}"`.

For your case, i believe it should be something like, `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance model:Producer}"`

Simple set it to your `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Up}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance model:Producer}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Up}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Up}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Can you please add it to my code so I will know where exactly to put this DataContext assignment?